Is there a way to set up a trade route optimization for a barter system in Excel (Microsoft 365)
I have a system that is set up like a barter economy where each state specializes in one product (which it will sell at a discount) and demands only one product (which it will purchase at a premium) which allows the opportunity for arbitrage.
Is it possible to set up an optimization problem in excel that can find the most profitable trade route under conditions like this?
The system assumes there is no cost for transportation outside of taking "1 trip" when moving from any state to any other state, and there is a constraint of about 20 trips. Travel time and distance is irrelevant, assume instantaneous.
There is no response from the market when making any trades.
The system that I have looks something like this:



State
Product Produced
Price to Purchase Product
Product demanded
Price You Can Sell Product




California
Apples
85
Oranges
110


Texas
Oranges
90
Apples
111


North Dakota
Grapes
80
Apples
115


Washington
Watermelon
86
Grapes
113


Utah
Potatoes
75
Pineapples
112



The economy has around 30 states with about 25 different products, and who is specializing in what/who wants what can change, so I can't just calculate the best route once and be done with it.
Closed loops like the one you see in the apples to oranges trade can happen, but aren't always going to be the most profitable. Revisiting a state is allowed, as is completely ignoring some states. Some products might not be produced, even though they are demanded, and some products might not be demanded even though they are produced.
If there is a method to solve for the optimal route from the table above which could also be expanded to different states/product combinations, then that would answer this question. Additionally, I would be interested in knowing if it could also be applied to a system that sells/demands more than one product per state,though I know that would be much more complicated to set up.
I went into this thinking I could put something together using the Excel Solver with some constraints but quickly realized that wasn't viable.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Take a look, they have APIs for routing and sequence optimization that run smoothly in Excel:

https://developer.myptv.com/en/resources/tutorials/general/how-use-ptv-developer-microsoft-excel
https://developer.myptv.com/en/documentation/sequence-optimization-api


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

These api seem to be prioritizing the importance of physically routing functioning paths rather than something that can be used to optimize arbitrage in trades like this. Is there one that you were thinking of that could be adapted to find an optimal trade sequence for the example I have?
